# What is the most natural new physics one can expect at the TeV scale: new (supersymmetric)particles or some new (non-commutative) spacetime structure?

Tags: research-level, higgs, neutrinos, majorana-fermions, non-commutative-geometry

Up to now, nothing else than one Standard Model (SM) Higgs boson-like resonance has been found at the LHC while many predictions based on effective theories using supersymmetry require several Higgs scalars and needs an entourage of sparticles close in mass to tame its quantum instabilities (I borrow more or less from [James D. Wells](http://books.google.fr/books?id=kKKAfrfCofcC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=james%20wells%20predictions%20based%20on%20effective%20theories%20%20require%20that%20the%20Higgs%20boson%20needs%20an%20entourage%20of%20particles%20close%20in%20mass%20to%20tame%20its%20quantum%20instabilities&source=bl&ots=VpWPssqr1d&sig=vKIWPRLTI7dgfH0bZuzWSXfwvIU&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=XvzLUYTuGcO2hAeRiYHwBg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=james%20wells%20predictions%20based%20on%20effective%20theories%20%20require%20that%20the%20Higgs%20boson%20needs%20an%20entourage%20of%20particles%20close%20in%20mass%20to%20tame%20its%20quantum%20instabilities&f=false)).

On the other hand, the spectral and almost-commutative extension of the SM by [Chamseddine and Connes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1030), expects only one Higgs boson without other particles in the TeV range. In this noncommutative approach  spacetime appears as the product (in the sense of ﬁbre bundles) of a continuous manifold by a discrete space and it has been proved by [Martinetti and Wulkenhaar](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0104108)  that under precise conditions, the metric aspect of ”continuum × discrete” spaces reduces to the simple picture of two copies of the manifold.

**Could it be that this picture of a two-sheets spacetime helps to overcome the technical naturalness issue related to the standard model Higgs (*replacing temptatively a low energy supersymmetry by a new geometric framework*) and has to be taken seriously in order to progress in the understanding of physics beyond the SM?**

To ask it differently:

**Reminding that the Standard model like Higgs boson is a *natural* consequence of the noncommutative geometric framework, could it be that the *discreteness of space-time* usually expected at the Planck scale from quantum gravity  already shows up *at the electroweak scale* through the very existence of the already discovered Higgs boson?**
(this formulation could require a new, yet to be defined, heuristic meaning for the term: *naturalness*)

Last but not least, it is worth noting that to postdict the correct mass of the Higgs boson detected at LHC8, the last version of the spectral model relies on a weak coupling with another scalar that shows up "naturally" in the spectral action just like the Higgs. This "[big brother](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1d2Dm4C3nSMC&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=big%20broson%20connes&source=bl&ots=vOYNMuyTuH&sig=kYYq_fYp5TWsvNghgqzglUGz_p8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=XODVUeCyF8KlPYG8gYgJ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=big%20broson%20connes&f=false)" from the Higgs boson is expected to acquire a vev generating a mass scale above $10^{11}GeV$ for right-handed Majorana neutrinos. It could thus be responsible for a type I see-saw mechanism explaining the neutrino phenomenology beyond the minimal SM.

*May be noncommutative geometry can help to make effective theories more alive and kicking!
In memoriam Ken Wilson*

*To celebrate the 4th of July "IndependentHiggsday", I wish a happy birthday to the lightest scalar field of the Standard Model and I congratulate experimentalists who work hard to prove physics is alive (and [not ordered](http://www.physicstoday.org/resource/1/phtoad/v53/i7/p15_s1?bypassSSO=1) by theories ;-)!*

EDIT : The title of the question has been changed in an attempt to improve clarity (after reading *[The Higgs: so simple yet so unnatural](http://indico.cern.ch/getFile.py/access?contribId=27&sessionId=3&resId=0&materialId=slides&confId=239571)*); the former title was:

> Doubling the number of elementary particles or "doubling space-time"
>   to accommodate Higgs boson phenomenology at 8TeV?

Comment: As far as I know, the noncommutative standard model still has a hierarchy problem; it doesn't predict the electroweak scale, it just constrains the possible masses of the Higgs, after many other SM parameters are specified.

Comment: -1:  This looks to me more like an advertisement than a real question

Comment: There actually is a question - it's the part in bold.

Comment: Regarding the hierarchy problem, adding a dilaton field, the spectral action contains purpotedly "all the essential features of building a scale invariant standard model interactions to generate a mass hierarchy and predict the Higgs mass ..." (http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512169) and to be more specific about fine tuning "the problem of explaining the very low mass scale of fermion masses reduces to explaining the origin of a dilaton vev of the order of 10^2" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0985). These claims were made before the last version of the spectral model.

Comment: I can understand the question looks like an advertisement but it is not (my profile explains my bias towards noncommutative geometry). It's just that reading recently "_Effective Field Theories and the Role of Consistency in Theory Choice_" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0634) from J.D. Wells it seems to me that _the effective theory derived from the almost commutative spectral model has a pretty strong_ **mathematical consistency** and happens to have _similarities with other effective theories_ having nice(r) **observational consistency** (than ones based on supersymmetry as far as I know).

Comment: I've looked through the NCG-physics literature, old and new, and it's claimed that their dilaton solution to the hierarchy problem works in the same way as the Randall-Sundrum model, where a small number (distance between the two branes, in the case of RS) serves as an exponent and produces the large difference between weak scale (Fermi scale) and GUT/Planck scale. The analogy with RS is said to be quite close. I can't judge it for myself yet.

Comment: The clarity of this question is not helped by the fact that the text now contains two questions, neither of which is in the title. the first question in the text is about naturalness, the second question is about discrete space-time, the title is about noncommutative geometry versus supersymmetry.

Comment: Dear @MitchellPorter, Regarding the analogy with RS, I think it is quite formal, there is no such thing as Kaluza-Klein modes or particles analogues in the spectral model for instance ... The most direct comparison between Noncommutative Geometry and Randall-Sundrum Models (in the context of alternatives to compactification) I know about is this article :  http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0009180

Comment: Dear @MitchellPorter I hope the last edit improves a little bit the clarity of my question. Otherwise I will side-step quoting Niels Bohr who said once : "... I don't like to speak more clearly than I think" (I would most humbly I can't write more clearly than I understand). Quotation from the book "Home Is Where the Wind Blows: Chapters from a Cosmologist's Life" by Sir Fred Hoyle

Comment: Who is close voting this high-level question claiming that it is rather opinion based? It is cristall clear that the OP looks for answers from a physics point of view, which is not the same as opinion based nonconstructive discussion  **Leave open**

Answer (score 1):

The paper you link to contains a model which is simply the Standard Model coupled to a singlet scalar. Its hierarchy problem is just as severe as that of the Standard Model, and as such it is a highly unnatural theory. (To be clear: what I mean by "unnatural" here is that the theory has quadratically divergent corrections to the Higgs mass, and as such the low-energy physics is highly sensitive to unknown ultraviolet parameters. As far as I can determine the Chamseddine/Connes scenario does nothing to tame the ultraviolet problems of quantum field theory.)

Comment: This answer completely ignores the non-commutative geometry derivation of this model, which makes this model more natural than it would be if you just considered conventional physics. (Unless you're using the technical particle physics meaning of "natural".)

Comment: Yes, of course I'm using the technical meaning of "natural," which I assumed was the meaning intended by the question. If not, I don't know what the question means. I'll edit.

Comment: The OP does say "giving then a rather nontechnical meaning to *naturalness*". I have to admit that I don't understand what the question means, either.

Comment: @PeterShor:  Since the bounty currently prevents us from closing this question as 'primarily opinion-based', I think it's only reasonable to assume that the term 'naturalness issue' used by OP must refer to technical naturalness.

Comment: Yes ... if the OP is talking about the English definition of "natural", this is clearly a "primarily-opinion-based" question, since it requires a comparison supersymmetry-based physics with non-commutative-geometry-based physics.

Comment: @Matt Reece: there is a much older paper by Chamseddine and Connes http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512169 which *does* claim technical naturalness for these noncommutative models, once you include the NC dilaton. The status of that idea is the real issue of substance here; I have been meaning to study it and comment, but haven't found the time yet.

Comment: @Mitchell Porter: that's pretty much a non-starter. There's no light dilaton in our universe, and gravity's far from conformal anyway. I've never seen an attempt to relate naturalness to scale invariance that made an ounce of sense to me.

Comment: I have edited the question to disambiguate the naturalness issue. In my question I clearly understand "naturalness" in the general perspective of 't Hooft : "it is our aim to use naturalness as a new guideline to construct models of elementary particles". But following Grinbaum  http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4055 I wonder if this kind of heuristic argument firstly aimed at showing "that this is the reason why light, weakly interacting scalar particles are not seen" (other quote from 't Hooft) has not came to a dead end in the usual (commutative?) quantum field framework.

Comment: I wonder if the noncommutative framework could not be a valuable tool to overcome this technical naturalness issue of the Higgs boson.

Comment: I am not an expert at all thus I don't pretend to correct any statement by Matt Reece in his answer. Nevertheless restricting the aforementionned work by Chamseddine and Connes as an effective _model_ and at the same time characterizing it as a highly unnatural _theory_ seems to me oversimplified and unfair. Anyway Matt Reece raises an important issue which is definitely not clearly settled enough in most articles by Chamseddine and Connes.

Comment: To carry on the last issue, I think Walter D. van Suijlekom works hard on the renormalizability of the asymptotically expanded spectral action considered as higher-derivative gauge theories showing that it contains natural higher-derivative UV regulators (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4690.pdf)...

Answer (score 0):

The  question is hard to answer not because of its colloquial character but because it tries to establish a comparison bewteen two predictions at the TeV scale sustained by two very different theoretical frameworks :

- the prediction of supersymmetric particles is made in the context of quantum renormalizable theory with fields interacting in a Minkowski 4D space-time;
- the existence of a fine structure (two-sheets) of spacetime comes with a spectral action principle on an almost-commutative geometric setting.

Despite this fundamental difference, I think it should be possible and interesting to compare them, debate about their mathematical and observational consistency as *two effective theories at the TeV scale*. I understand *effective theories* in the modern viewpoint very pedagogically explained by Matthew Schwartz in [this lecture note](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic473482.files/22-nonrenormalizable.pdf).

I think it's worth emphasizing that **the technical naturalness issue of the Standard Model Higgs boson exists only if one assumes that it is embedded in a larger renormalizable theory** that goes along the line of conventional QFT on Minkowski 4D space-time(*I would appreciate to be corrected if I am wrong on this statement*).

Insofar as the spectral action principle, applied on a crude almost-commutative geometry and with a Planck-scale cut-off, already proves to be able to deliver the Einstein-Hilbert and the Standard Model Yang-Mill-Higgs terms, **it is not unreasonable to *expect* that noncommutative geometry offers *another embedding* of the Standard Model to some kind of UV completion with degrees of freedom that would be different from customary QFT in 4D Minkowski space-time**. This [recent article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0415)(2013) for instance goes along such lines proposing a *different noncommutative structure which mixes spin and gauge degrees of freedom* in a very specific way.

Nevertheless if one want to stick on the naturalness problem of the electroweak scale it could be interesting to reassess in the light of recent developments the former tentative to look at noncommutative geometry as [another alternative to compactification](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0009180)(1999). Indeed a almost-commutative toy model on a two-sheeted spacetime with a gravitational and U(1) gauge fields was proved to give a Randall-Sundrum potential for the Higgs field with the correct *exponential term to reduce the natural scale of the electroweak symmetry breaking from the Planck scale to the TeV* scale without fine tuning.
I quote :

> *We notice that the non diagonal elements of the matrix algebra, and of
>   the Dirac operator, have a twofold interpretation. On one side they
>   are the Higgs ﬁeld in the gauge setting, whose natural scale is the
>   electroweak scale. On the other side they appear as the discrete
>   component of the Levi–Civita connection, with a natural gravitational
>   (Planck) scale. It is this dual role which solves the hierarchy
>   problem in this setting*

It would be interesting to investigate if the exponential term appearing in the 1999 article has some connection with the new singlet scalar field proposed by Chamseddines and Connes in 2012 to postdict the correct mass of the physical Higgs boson observed at LHC8 ...(beyond the mere coïncidence of the [sigma labelling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/is-the-conjectured-noncommutative-heavy-scalar-brother-of-the-already-detected) for the new degree of freedom in both papers, just a convenient notation for a generic singlet scalar field I guess)!

Comment about the bounty: 
The bounty period beeing over, I thank Matt Reece for proposing an answer but I can't accept it for the very reason given by Peter Shor in his comment. I thank also Mitchell Porter to make constructive remarks. I feel free now to propose my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice : This is another *tentative answer to address (better than in my former one) the naturalness problem raised by the present stalemate for traditional perturbatively renormalisable Susy-Yang-Mill-Higgs quantum field theories in the LHC phenomenology*. It can be formulated briefly as an "educated" guess blending some condensed matter physics intuition and non-commutative vision :

The **fine structure of spacetime at the electroweak scale could act as a non-commutative protectorate, ensuring a non-commutative safety mechanism that protects the low mass of the Higgs from diverging quantum corrections up to the Planck scale**, just like masses of spin 1/2 fermions are protected by "chirality" and spin 1 bosons are protected by gauge invariance.

That would explain why SUSY predictions in the conceptual framework of perturbatively renormalisable quantum field theory on the usual four dimensional commutative space-time fails because probing the physics of the Higgs to go beyond the Standard Model probably requires not only to go over much higher energies but also to work with the proper spacetime framework. To make a crude comparison : analysing sound waves with the effective theory of hydrodynamics cannot help the physicist to uncover the atomic structure of matter but listening to the insight gained by the chemist who understood conceptually how to shape matter may help ...

Moreover **progress in the understanding of [how non-commutativity could modify the renormalization group flow for the Higgs couplings](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5023) is already underway**.

Then maybe once the proper non-commutative constraint is correctly implemented in physics model-building, one will witness a new increase in "[the price of shares of stock in Quantum Field Theory](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1188567?ln=fr)" to quote Weinberg. After all, the Standard Model emerged in the 70s taking seriously non-Abelian gauge groups envisioned in the 50s and thanks to the conceptual understanding of asymptotic freedom in chromodynamics, I remind that this last part is still conjectural today! Then it would be quite natural to go beyond the Standard Model in the 2010s thanks to some new non-commutative geometric ideas developed in the 90s that explain the quantum spontaneous breaking of electroweak symmetry imagined in the 60s!

Of course this kind of hypothetical heuristics and epistemological retro-analysis is definitely not a technical answer and I could understand that such a speculation is not suited for Physics SE (I am ready to remove it if required). Adding an "epistemology" tag would have helped but there were allready 5 of them.

Remark : I found interesting and inspiring ideas about renormalization in the non-commutative context (but very different from the Higgs) in [this article](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0705.0705) by V. Rivasseau.